# Can't Link <a href="#"> W/ PHP code

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to link `$child['id']` but can't do it. Link is removed on line 13. Can anyone tell me correct way to generate category link on click?

```
<!-- fetch parent categories -->
<?php
while ($parent = mysqli_fetch_assoc($parentquery)) : ?>

<?php
$parent_id=$parent['cat_id'];?>

<!--fetch sub-categories-->
<?php
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE cat_parent = '$parent_id'";
$child_query = $db->query($sql2); // database object
?>

<div class="col-menu col-md-3">
<h6 class="title"><?php echo $parent['cat_name'] ?></h6>

<div class="content">
<ul class="menu-col">
<?php while($child = mysqli_fetch_assoc($child_query)) : ?>
```

Now I want to link each category on the below. Loops works fine. I am seeing category names but no link. Please help

```
<li> <a href='#'>
<?php echo $child['cat_name']; ?></a></li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Uhm... What...?

Comment: <a href='#'> .. I want to link it to the category id when clicked on it.

Comment: Okay, and what's the problem?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: @tadman ← what he said²

Comment: Also please fix your indentation

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass it in href

```
<li> 
   <a href='<?php echo $child['link'];?'>
       <?php echo $child['cat_name']; ?>
   </a>
</li>
```

Try this if ur href is empty then you should add

```
<a href='"<?php echo $child['link'];?>"'> // double quotes
```

Answer (score 0):

you should pass the id to the `href`,

```
<a href='<?=$child['id'];?>'>
```